# How to get HE-AAC audio type?

Tags: c++, audio, audio-streaming, android-mediacodec

Im trying to write simple audio stream/media player in C/C++. The problem is that some of the streams I must play is HE-AAC. Here is my code to detect audio types from raw data:

```
int Audio_GetType(const uint8_t *pData)
{
    if ((pData[0] == 0xFF) && ((pData[1] & 0xE0) == 0xE0))
    {
        if ((((pData[1] & 0x06) >> 1) != 0x00) &&
            (((pData[2] & 0xF0) >> 4) != 0x0F) &&
            (((pData[2] & 0x0C) >> 2) != 0x03))
        {
            return TYPE_MP3;
        }
    }

    if ((pData[0] == 0xFF) && ((pData[1] & 0xF0) == 0xF0))
    {
        return TYPE_AAC;
    }

    if ((pData[0] == 0x0B) && (pData[1] == 0x77))
    {
        return TYPE_AC3;
    }

    return TYPE_INVALID;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get if stream is HE-AAC? For example I can find ADTS AAC with `0xFF` sync like that `(pData[0] == 0xFF) && ((pData[1] & 0xF0) == 0xF0)`.

How can I know that stream is HE-AAC?

Comment: If it's in ADTS, you need to unwrap the HE-AAC stream from it first.